# Adding millions of records at the same time

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have got an asp.net MVC 5 app that I use to store data. There are about a total 85 million records in 10 different excel files. I upload an excel file and the systems stores the records in the file to my database. This takes a lot of time though, 65K records take around 1 hour or so. Is there any way I can speed this up? Are these speeds normal?

The app is hosted on my local host so internet speed isn't an issue. I checked and the system writes around 15 records per second.

I'm using MVC 5 with MS SQL. The code the reads from file and writes to excel is:

```
                //Reads excel file using ExcelDataReader Package
                var dataTable = result.Tables[0];

                //Read each row one by one
                for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //Read Properties
                    var FName = dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString().Trim(); //First Name
                    //This goes on, I have 11 properties

                    //Create DbEntity
                    var dbEntity = new DbEntity
                    {
                        FirstName = FName,
                        //Do the same for all other properties
                    };

                    var entities = db.DbEntities.Where(d => d.Phone == dbEntity.Phone).ToList();

                    if (entities.Count() > 0) 
                    {
                        //If it is duplicate, set IsDuplicate to true
                        dbEntity.IsDuplicate = true;

                        //Set occurance = count(entities) + 1
                        dbEntity.Ocurance = entities.Count() + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //If the entity is unique, set IsDuplicate to false
                        dbEntity.IsDuplicate = false;

                        //Set the occurance to 1
                        dbEntity.Ocurance = 1;
                    }

                    //Set WasSent to false
                    dbEntity.WasSent = false;

                    //Add Entity to records
                    if(dbEntity.Phone.Length == 10)
                    {
                        db.DbEntities.Add(dbEntity);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        ++validCount;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //If record is not valid, skip it and add it to invalidRec list
                        invalidRecs.Add(dbEntity);
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
                //Sending result data to View

                var data = new ImportResultViewModel
                {
                    ValidCount = validCount,
                    InvalidList = invalidRecs
                };
                return View("ImportResult",data);
            }
```

As you can see, I add each record one by one. Would it be better if I keep all the valid records in a list and then add the whole list to the database in the end? Would that improve the performance?

Comment: You didn't provide any pertinent details.  What DB?  What technology are you using to connect to the DB?  Show us the code you're using to write the records.

Comment: Sql Server? If so do some research on bulk insert or SSIS packages which should be significantly faster than doing it via code. Whether you *can* do it though depends on a lot of other factors. In short you need to do more research or provide much more detail in your question.

Comment: Sorry, updated the question with code.

Comment: Generate a `List<DbEntity>()` and use `db.DbEntities.AddRange(dbEntities)`.  Let's say, do a batch of 100, then addrange and then SaveChanges().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario, I would highly recommend staying clear of Entity Framework, at least for this function. In pure SQL/ Ado.Net, you can use a BulkInsert that would handle your request within a few seconds, 85k isn't all that much to a transaction, especially if your SQL server has even half-decent specs. Another Nuget package, that seems to have been deprecated (I still use it in production code, but I have also performed an audit on the code,) is

https://libraries.io/nuget/SqlBulkTools.

I feel confident using it in production, but everyone's parameters are different. If you really want to squeeze out the performance and prefer ADO.Net (raw), there are still two options available :

(BulkCopy) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/single-bulk-copy-operations

or

(Batch DataTable Adapter) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performing-batch-operations-using-dataadapters